# PhoenixNonRetryableRuntimeException: Could not load/instantiate class org.apache.phoenix.query.DefaultGuidePostsCacheFactory (from database clients))

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

I am trying to use various database clients (Squirrel 4.1.0, DBVisualizer Free 12.1.1) to connect to an HBase database, but I get an error:

> PhoenixNonRetryableRuntimeException: Could not load/instantiate class
> org.apache.phoenix.query.DefaultGuidePostsCacheFactory

In the image below, you can see that I've put `phoenix-client-hbase-2.4-5.1.2.jar` into the extra class path, and in the image below that, you can see that the jar contains `DefaultGuidePostsCacheFactory.class`.

Why can't Squirrel or DBVisualizer find the class?  Another post suggested that Squirrel needs to be restarted after modifying the classpath, but I've done that.  Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue with phoenix-hbase-2.4-5.1.3.

Have you found a solution or root cause?